# The SSL connection to the remote server could not be established

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am getting SSL connection to the remote server could not be established, in my rails app when trying to pay through paypal. Integration works fine with development and test environment (paypal sandbox) but not working in production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal has upgrade TLS to 1.2:
https://devblog.paypal.com/upcoming-security-changes-notice/

You need to upgrade your openssl version to support **TLS 1.2**.

If you are using **Ubuntu 12.04** you can upgrade openssl with:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade openssl
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade libssl-dev
```

For other systems, check this support page from Stripe:

https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-do-i-upgrade-my-openssl-to-support-tls-1-2

Answer (score 0):

try to change in `config/initializers/openssl.rb` the value of `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:ssl_version]` from `:TLSv1` to `"SSLv23_client"`
and restart the server